# Print all numbers below "x" in an array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to print out the numbers below the number scanned (x). I have no idea how though, all I have so far is how to print only the lowest number of the array. Don't know how i can include x into my last loop. So if i type x = 13, i want it to print out 11, 7, 5, 3, 2.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


        //1

        int[] num= {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19};

        for(int i=0; i<num.length; i++) {

        System.out.println("Num: " + num[i]);
        }

        // 2
        System.out.print("\n Type a number: ");

        int x = scan.nextInt();

        x = num[0];
        for (int i=1; i>=num.length; i++) {
        if(num[i] < x) {
            x = num[i];
        }
        }
        System.out.println("Numbers below" + x);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can change the for loop start and end limit :D

Comment: Do you really want `i>=num.length`?

Comment: If it's homework you should tag with `homework` :)

Comment: What is the purpose of  x=num[0]?

Comment: to be honest, i have no idea how to do it. i just knew i needed a for-loop to find the lowest number. edit all you want :)

Comment: When the index of the item isn't important, use a for-each loop.  You may also want to look up the `print` (not `println`) method, which may give you some ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this:

```
System.out.println("Numbers below " + x);
for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
    if (num[i] < x) {
        System.out.println(num[i]);
    }
}
```

Here is a `List` version with foreach loop:

```
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int n: num) {
       if (n < x) {
          list.add(n);
       }
    }
    System.out.println("Numbers below " + x + ": " + list);
```

output:

```
Numbers below 13: [2, 3, 5, 7, 11]
```

Answer (score 6):

You're not printing anything in the for-loop, and even if you were, the for-loop itself looks a little strange. Did you mean `i < num.length`? And why are you re-assigning `x` to `num[0]`? Try this:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < num.length ; i++)
    if (num[i] < x)
        System.out.println(num[i]);
```

(Make sure to delete the `x = num[0]` line.)

Just as a note, you can also use a for-each loop:

```
for (int a : num)
    if (a < x)
        System.out.println(a);
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with this line `System.out.println("Numbers below" + x);`, this must be in the for loop within if block but with some change as this `System.out.println(num[i]);` as you want to print the element of array which are accessed by num[i] not your choice `x`.

**Assuming you want to print the elements in the array in the order as you mentioned**....`So if i type x = 13, i want it to print out 11, 7, 5, 3, 2.` , following code will do this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] num = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19 };

        for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {

            System.out.println(num[i]);
        }

        System.out.print("Type a number: ");

        int x = scan.nextInt();
        // Removing the below statement as it makes no sense.
        // x = num[0];

        // Looping in this sense after supposing you need to print the number in
        // reverse order as per the question.

        System.out.println("Numbers below");

        //looping in the reverse order to meet the requirement
        for (int i = num.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (x > num[i]) {
                System.out.println(num[i]);
            }
        }
        // Moving this line in for loop within if block, but instead of x, we print num[i]
        //System.out.println("Numbers below" + x);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems fine. Except you must iterate over all the items of the array (after typing a number).

Your code is evaluating `i>=num.length` **but it must be `i<num.length`** because it's the same as the previous loop (iterate over all the items).

Also the starting value should be 0, because the first position in an array is 0.

So, you should do:

```
for (int i=0; i<num.length; i++) {
    if (num[i] < x) { // if this value is lower than the entered value (x)
       System.out.println(num[i]); // then I print it
}
```

Note than **you don't have to reassign x**. x is the entered value you don't want to change it. You need it to know if each item of the array is lower than it.

Comment: No, don't do that if you're looping over all items in an array.  Use a for-each loop.  Use this form if you need the index (not necessary in this case, for a couple of reasons).

Comment: You're right. The best way is `for(int value: num)`. But for learning reasons (and not changing a lot) indexed-for is ok.